# Will this use of jQuery slow page display times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, event-handling

I have about 300+ action links on a page, to which I’m connecting handlers after the `document.onready` event fires (using jQuery):

```
$('a.cmd').click (function() { ... do stuff ... });
```

Is it more efficient to incorporate the `onclick` handlers into the HTML rather than have jQuery attach them after the DOM elements have been created?

```
<a onclick="... do stuff ...">
```

Comment: Wow, 300 actions on a page...just out of curiosity, what it this page doing?

Comment: Up to 50 items on a page * 6 possible actions per item...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will it slow it down? Yes binding takes time, no matter how much it does take *some* time.  However, there are some ways to really improve your situation here.

It's actually better to use a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) handler here, so your initial binding cost is *significantly* less, like this:

```
$('a.cmd').live('click', function() { /* do stuff */ });
```

Or better:

```
$(document.body).delegate('a.cmd', 'click', function() { /* do stuff */ });
```

In both of these cases instead of attaching a handler *to each DOM element*, we're attaching *one* event handler to `document` (or `<body>` in the case of the second example).  This means significantly less startup cost for the page.

Comment: Why is `delegate()`-ing to document.body better?

Comment: @Matt - because it doesn't run the `a.cmd` selector until it's needed...with `.live()` that set of elements is fetched then just thrown away.

Comment: @Matt - it's not...imagine a more expensive selector, like `$('[attr=value]')`...that's a *very* expensive selector running on all elements, it's a *huge* difference...especially when you consider it's running for no reason.

Comment: Yes, but it's only going to run once over the lifetime of the page.

Comment: @Matt - Why run it at all? you're dismissing it as a 0 cost, in older browsers selectors are much more expensive, people tend to forget this when developing in browsers that support `querySelectorAll()` and such.

Answer (score 2):

Inline event handlers will definitely not be more efficient *per se*. The both methods create a large number of listeners.

The efficient way to do this is with [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate).

```
$('a.cmd').live('click', function () { /* do stuff */ });
```

---

If you're already using jQuery, there is almost never a compelling reason to use inline (in HTML) event handler binding.